# Can Random.Next() be predicted from its outputs

Tags: c#, .net, security, random

Having this (simplified) C# class:

```
public static class RandomValue
{
    private static readonly Random s_random = new Random();

    public static int GetRandomValue()
    {
        lock (s_random)
        {
            return s_random.Next();
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to predict the next value of `GetRandomValue()` by looking at the values generated by this method?

Assumptions (for the sake of the question):

- The attacker does *not* know the seed (of course).
- The attacker can observe an unlimited number of subsequent results of `GetRandomValue()`.

I'm asking because I've seen some code using a similar approach to generate some kind of access tokens. This code was not written by me and I would probably have used one of .NET's crypto random classes. I'm just curious whether this is still sufficiently secure.

Comment: In the comments to [this article](https://jazzy.id.au/2010/09/22/cracking_random_number_generators_part_3.html) someone discusses using the concepts discussed to attack `System.Random`.

Comment: Not sure about your original question, but that looks like it won't even guarantee that any one thread will get a uniform distribution. Assuming that the applications using this RNG might be both multi-threaded (e.g. a web server) and use one thread at a time to produce access tokens, it's more likely than not that this is actually a problem. Regardless of predictability, that doesn't seem secure to me (but I'm definitely not an expert on security or cryptography).

Comment: I think observing 57 values is enough to predict the rest http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,100 .

Comment: `System.Random` was never designed to be cryptographically secure. In fact, it was designed for determinism. It is often the case that you want to be able to produce a repeatable random number stream. For secure random numbers you want to use [RandomNumberGenerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: No it is not cryptographically secure -- it was not designed to be.  A cryptographically secure PRNG needs to do a lot more work, and hence runs more slowly.  It has to gather entropy/randomness where it can and it has to reseed itself frequently.  It also uses cryptographic processes internally, which again slow it down.  See [Fortuna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortuna_(PRNG)) for an example of a CSPRNG.

Comment: The answer is a clever solution but you also can just try all 2 billion seeds. Takes a few minutes. This works with any generator with a small seed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on kennytm's comment I created a proof of concept on how to to "break" `Random`. It may be a little rough around the edges but it shows that you only need 55 values to predict the next one (and every value after that).

The following code first reads 55 values from a single `Random` instance and then predicts the next 10 values:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int INTERNAL_ARRAY_SIZE = 56;
        const int INEXTP_START = 21;

        var internalArray = new int[INTERNAL_ARRAY_SIZE];

        var random = new Random();

        // Read 56 values.
        for (int x = 0; x < INTERNAL_ARRAY_SIZE - 1; x++)
        {
            internalArray[x + 1] =  random.Next();
        }

        int inext = INTERNAL_ARRAY_SIZE - 1;
        int inextp = INEXTP_START;

        // Predict the next 10 values.
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            int predictedRandomValue = PredictNextRandomValue(internalArray, ref inext, ref inextp);
            int officialRandomValue = random.Next();

            if (officialRandomValue == predictedRandomValue)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yes, they're the same.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No, they're different.");
            }
        }
    }

    private static int PredictNextRandomValue(int[] seedArray, ref int inext, ref int inextp)
    {
        const int MBIG =  int.MaxValue;

        int retVal;
        int locINext = inext;
        int locINextp = inextp;

        if (++locINext >= 56) locINext = 1;
        if (++locINextp >= 56) locINextp = 1;

        retVal = seedArray[locINext] - seedArray[locINextp];

        if (retVal == MBIG) retVal--;
        if (retVal < 0) retVal += MBIG;

        seedArray[locINext] = retVal;

        inext = locINext;
        inextp = locINextp;

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is PredictNextRandomValue defined?

Comment: @BillSambrone - There is a function below if you scroll down. Or were you referring to something else?

Comment: Doesnt seem to work in .Net 6.0 anymore